# Errors in Android NDK Project in Eclipse IDE after Importing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I created a project that utilizes the Android NDK. It works fine in the workspace I first created it in. However if I try to import the project into a different workspace I can no longer view let alone edit any of the JNI files. The minute I open a file under the JNI folder the project stops compiling and running. Note, this occurs even without saving the file just simply opening it. This can be fixed by removing the project from the workspace and reimporting it.

This is a large hindrance if I want to have any one else work with the JNI code. They can change the Java code without issues.

IS this some weird bug with project set up, or simply a bug in the Eclipse NDK plugin?